# Executing SQL query using python doesn't do anything

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm coding a tracking stock prices program. I'm trying to execute INSERT query and it executes, but doesn't do anything.

Here's my method in my class SQLDatabaseOperator

```
def insert_data_to_database(self, ticker_name, api_data_dict):
    self.connect_to_database()

    sqlite_insert_data_query = '''INSERT INTO {}(open_price, high_price, low_price, previous_close_price, date)\
                                                  VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {}, 'data');'''.format(ticker_name,\
                                                                                            api_data_dict['o'],\
                                                                                            api_data_dict['h'],\
                                                                                            api_data_dict['l'],\
                                                                                            api_data_dict['pc'])
    cursor = self.sqliteConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_data_query)
    cursor.close()
    self.close_connection()
```

And here's my sample test.

```
name = 'NIO'
data = {'o': 24.123, 'h': 30.02, 'l': 22.03, 'pc': 23}
test = SQLDatabaseOperator()
test.insert_data_to_database(name, data)
```

Nothing is in the database. I don't know what to do. I'm using SQLite. This is my database.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you call `self.sqliteConnection.commit()` after the INSERT query.

Comment: @mechanical_meat before or after cursor.execute() ?

Comment: After `cursor.execute()`, but before you're closing the connection.

Comment: @mechanical_meat THANK YOU VERY MUCH, It solved my problem!

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answear was simple - I just need to use

```
self.sqliteConnection.commit()
```

after executing cursor. Regards for https://stackoverflow.com/users/42346/mechanical-meat for solving my problem.